# Collision Detection algorithm for Selection advice

Tags: algorithm, collision-detection, graph-theory, collision

I don't know if this is proper platform for the question. 
I'm trying to develop a collision detection algorithm.
In my system the primary host (a vehicle) is either stationary or is in motion (in xy, yz and xz plane).
Incoming projectile can either follow a strait path or non-linear trajectory (guided projectile).
Can anyone advice me on proper Collision Detection algorithm!
Initially I thought in terms of equation of a straight line in two-point and further extrapolating (using linear regression) to check if the projectile is impacting the host. This approach might work for unguided or high speed projectile but however on guided projectile this approach will not work due non-linearity and stochastic nature of real-world.
I wish to know if the projectile follows a ballistic trajectory or curved trajectory how can I detect collision. Is their any recommended algorithm.

I have created a Minimum bounding box (i.e. vehicle boundary - a cube) around my vehicle, I am having difficulty selecting/deciding on algorithm on how to track a projectile (say 400 meters away), if the projectile is converging/impacting on my vehicle boundary.

Comment: I would create a bounding boy around your vehicle and check if the projectile is within the bounding box -> vehicle is it.

Comment: @MrSmith42, I have created a Minimum bounding box (i.e. vehicle boundary - a cube) around my vehicle, I am having difficulty selecting/deciding on algorithm on how to track a projectile (say 400 meters away), if the projectile is converging/impacting on my vehicle boundary.

Comment: Not sure what your problem is. It's easy to check if the coordinates of the projectile are within the box. What else do you need?

Comment: We really need a bit more information about your application. Is it a simulation? A game? Offline calculation, real-time? What kind of precision and performance do you need, and do you have a concept of frames/ticks which can be considered elementary units for events? You can certainly calculate the exact intersection between a parabola and geometry, but it may not be the easiest or fastest solution. If you have guided projectiles too, then you need to define a model for those.